# looping Html video from script in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am playing video with using seekStart and seekEnd values and I want to repeat video When Video is ended,I am running below code When video is starting in 10 seconds and pause at 20 seconds video is not running again. How can I do this?

```
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
        var source = document.createElement('source');
     //set Volume
        document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].volume = volume / 10;
     //set src 
        source.setAttribute('src', fileName);
        video.appendChild(source);
     //set seekStart
        video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',function(){
            this.currentTime = seekStart;   
        },false);


     //set SeekEnd     
        video.addEventListener('timeupdate',function(){
             if(this.currentTime > seekEnd){
                 this.pause();
             }   
        });
     //looping
         video.addEventListener('ended', function () {

            this.play();

        }, false);


        video.play();
```

Comment: Did you try `video.setAttribute('loop', true)`  ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want the seeking functionality to work, but to loop back to the start when a video ends you need to also set the time back to the start:

```js
    video.addEventListener('ended', function () {

            this.currentTime = 0;
            this.play();

        }, false);
```